# Linux - moving files from source to destination with overwrite

Tags: linux, administration

Firstly I'd like to apologize if I duplicated a questions which already exists but it's too important to screw this.

I have two directories on my linux server: 
 - `/tmp`/tmp as source
 - `/var` as destination

There are already like 500 txt files in `/var` directory and I'd like to move all my files from `/tmp` directory (about 200 files) to `/var` directory with replacing those ones which already exist with the same name but as well as not touching those ones which are not in `/tmp`.

Practical example: 
`/var` files: a.txt , b.txt , c.txt , d.txt
`/tmp` files: a.txt , b.txt
Result: `/var` files: a.txt(from `/tmp`) , b.txt(from `/tmp`) , c.txt , d.txt

Not sure if `mv` is a proper method to do that, so thank you in advance guys! :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be implemented through `rsync`

Refer [rsync manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for more information.

```
Local:  rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]
Access via remote shell:
  Pull: rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST:SRC... [DEST]
  Push: rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST:DEST
Access via rsync daemon:
  Pull: rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST::SRC... [DEST]
        rsync [OPTION...] rsync://[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/SRC... [DEST]
  Push: rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST::DEST
        rsync [OPTION...] SRC... rsync://[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/DEST
```

For your case,

```
rsync -avzh /tmp/ /var/
```

If you want to test it

```
rsync -avzh --dry-run /tmp/ /var/

-a, --archive               archive mode;
-v, --verbose               increase verbosity
-z, --compress              compress file data during the transfer
-h, --human-readable        output numbers in a human-readable format
```

Detailed commentary

> -v, --verbose This option increases the amount of information you are given during the transfer. By default, rsync works silently. A single
>   -v will give you information about what files are being transferred and a brief summary at the end. Two -v options will give you
>   information on what files are being skipped and slightly more
>   information at the end. More than two -v options should only be used
>   if you are debugging rsync. Note that the names of the transferred
>   files that are output are done using a default --out-format of
>   lq%n%Lrq, which tells you just the name of the file and, if the item
>   is a link, where it points. At the single -v level of verbosity, this
>   does not mention when a file gets its attributes changed. If you ask
>   for an itemized list of changed attributes (either --itemize-changes
>   or adding lq%irq to the --out-format setting), the output (on the
>   client) increases to mention all items that are changed in any way.
>   See the --out-format option for more details.
>
> -a, --archive This is equivalent to -rlptgoD. It is a quick way of saying you want recursion and want to preserve almost everything (with
>   -H being a notable omission). The only exception to the above equivalence is when --files-from is specified, in which case -r is not
>   implied. Note that -a does not preserve hardlinks, because finding
>   multiply-linked files is expensive. You must separately specify -H.
>   --no-OPTION You may turn off one or more implied options by prefixing the option name with lqno-rq. Not all options may be prefixed with a
>   lqno-rq: only options that are implied by other options (e.g. --no-D,
>   --no-perms) or have different defaults in various circumstances (e.g. --no-whole-file, --no-blocking-io, --no-dirs). You may specify either the short or the long option name after the lqno-rq prefix (e.g.
>   --no-R is the same as --no-relative). For example: if you want to use -a (--archive) but don't want
>   -o (--owner), instead of converting -a into -rlptgD, you could specify -a --no-o (or -a --no-owner). The order of the options is important: if you specify --no-r -a, the
>   -r option would end up being turned on, the opposite of -a --no-r. Note also that the side-effects of the --files-from option are NOT
>   positional, as it affects the default state of several options and
>   slightly changes the meaning of -a (see the --files-from option for
>   more details).
>
> -z, --compress With this option, rsync compresses the file data as it is sent to the destination machine, which reduces the amount of data
>   being transmitted -- something that is useful over a slow connection.
>   Note that this option typically achieves better compression ratios
>   than can be achieved by using a compressing remote shell or a
>   compressing transport because it takes advantage of the implicit
>   information in the matching data blocks that are not explicitly sent
>   over the connection.
>
> -h, --human-readable Output numbers in a more human-readable format. This makes big numbers output using larger units, with a K, M, or G
>   suffix. If this option was specified once, these units are K (1000), M
>   (1000*1000), and G (1000*1000*1000); if the option is repeated, the
>   units are powers of 1024 instead of 1000.

Comment: I've already tested rsync and it works as I expected. Thank you.

Anyway, could u tell me, why do we use -a , -z, -h options in that case?

Comment: Edited to add comments from the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You cannot merge two directories using mv command simply. You can use either of the following ways:

1) You can use `cp` and `rm` commands to achieve your purpose.

```
$ cp -r /var /tmp
$ rm -rf /var
```

2) Using `rsync`, you can achieve that but rsync doesn't actyally "move" as per your question. It rather copies from one location to other(usually remote).

```
$ rsync -a -v /var /tmp
$ rm -r /var
```

I think this should serve the purpose. Cheers!

Comment: `rsync` can also "move" files if flag `--remove-source-files` is used.